# Protecting client's data over the wire

Tags: tls

I'm writing some security software, and don't want anyone to be able

to intercept data as its passed from client->server, and server->client.

The best way to do this is over HTTPS via SSL. However, I've read that you can't trust HTTPS,

as Certificate Authorities can get hacked, or taken over by Governments.

I've also read it's almost always a bad idea, and counter productive

to do some sort of Javascript crypto on the data before it's submitted.

So - how do I securely pass data between server and client?